# Какая разница между Telegram AbilityBot и обычным ботом (TelegramLongPollingBot)?

Tags: java, telegram, telegrambots

Я писал обычно ботов для телеграма с помощью обычной библиотеки и всегда обходил стороной раздел `AbilityBot`. Можете объяснить в каких случаях нужен `AbilityBot`, а в каких `TelegramLongPollingBot`? И может ли `AbilityBot` полностью заменить `TelegramLongPollingBot`?

Вот раздел "обычного бота" в [гитхаб](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Getting-Started)
Вот раздел "AbilityBot" в [гитхаб](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Simple-Example)